# Perform vitest debugging in IDEA:(node:27064) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, vitest

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgBRH.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnSSq.png)
(node:11816) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

The IDEA is expected to support normal debugging.

Comment: what does your run configuration look like? Please share a screenshot of it. Also, what IDE version do you use?